# How to keep list changes when program ends?

Tags: python, windows, list, tkinter, pickle

I have made simple Submit score option. User inputs name and score, and they are save to the list. List saves only top 10 scores. Than, list is printed to .txt file. But it works only while program is working. When i start it again, there's only default score in .txt file. User scores weren't saved. I'm using pickle module for that.

This is piece of my code. It's Python 3.4 and Tkinter.
Keep on mind that I'm learning python.

```
# This is inside class
#  ...
#  ...

    self.printto = tk.Button(self, text="Submit",
                             command=self.highscore
                             )
    self.printto.pack(side="left")

    self.high_scores = [
        ('Liz', 1800)
    ]

def highscore(self):
    name = self.name_ent.get()
    score = int(self.score_ent.get())

    self.high_scores.append((name, score))
    high_scores = sorted(self.high_scores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]

    with open('D:\Desktop/mytext.txt', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(high_scores, f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only saving data to file, but you are not reading it. You must open the file at the beginning of the program and read scores from it.

```
with open('D:\Desktop/mytext.txt', 'rb') as f:
    high_scores = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: @pythoner: you already found the `pickle` module; did you check that module and look at the `pickle.load()` method?

Comment: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: @pythoner: without a traceback that's not something we can troubleshoot. You are using a `str` object somewhere where bytes were expected.

Answer (score -1):

Few things
First thing: your the problem is here

```
with open('D:\Desktop/mytext.txt', 'wb') as f:
```

you open a file, not in append mode, but in creation, so each time you want to write something into a file, you just overwrite existing. You might want to read it first and compare with the date you are going to write, to get top 10 scores.

Second thing:
Using `pickle` to save a list with `strings/ints` is sort of overkill. Use `json.dumps/loads` instead

Comment: You don't want to append pickles. You want to use `w` to *replace* the old list with the updated list. `pickle` works just fine here, JSON is a nice alternative but not necessarily a problem here.

Answer (score -1):

are you looking for something like this? to read the score on your text file

```
user_score = {}
with open('D:\Desktop/mytext.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       #add user and score to user_score here
```